# Calling dateaxis function using handles in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-guide, axes

As you know we can call different plotting functions using MATLAB handles like:

```
plot(handles.axes,data);
hold(handles.axes,'on')
plot(handles.axes,ab2,data2,':r');
title(handles.axes','my title');
legend(handles.axes,'mm','ab','Location','Best');
grid on;
ylabel(handles.axes,'y label);
```

How we can call `dateaxis` function using handles? I want convert my x-axes values to dates. `dateaxis(handles.axes,12)` didn't work.

Comment: Maybe use [datetick](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html)?

Comment: Good job! . Please add your answer. thanks.

Comment: haha good! I just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely want to use [datetick](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html), which allows you to specify the axes to which you wish to apply changes in the same way as with `plot`:

```
datetick(axes_handle,...)
```